# Export Crystal Report rpt file to Excel without can grow format object

Tags: asp.net, excel, crystal-reports

I am exporting Crystal Report to Excel file using Crystal Report version 13 and VS 2013.

When I tried to export the Crystal Report file to Excel, the columns are merged. I need to unmerge all the fields at runtime so that I can manipulate data in an Excel sheet. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 15-page SAP document describing various aspects of designing Crystal Reports so they export as expected to Excel. Link is [here](https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-6687). In your case, the most important guideline is probably to **make sure all objects that overlap vertically are perfectly aligned and have the same width.**

You may want to consider using Excel (Data Only) export format to get better output. Similarly, you may find that exporting to Tab Separated (TTX) file produces cleaner output when opened in Excel.

Comment: It helps me a lot and also saves my time. Thanks again